# Oracle row diff

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have a EMPLOYEE_AUDIT table like this

```
   Employee_id Revision First_name  Last_Name  Gender    Position
   1           1        David       Hem        Male      Developer
   1           2        David       Hem        Male      Manager
   1           3        David       Alter      Male      Manager
   2           1        Agatha      Christie   Female    Business Analyst
   2           2        Agatha      Christie   Female    Group Manager
   2           3        Agatha      Christie   Female    General Manager
```

and i need a sql query with Output like this

```
   Column_name   employee_id Revision Old_Value         new_value
   Position      1           2        Developer         Manager
   Last_name     1           3        Hem               Alter
   Position      2           2        Business Analyst  Group Manager
   Position      2           3        Group Manager     General Manager
```

We are using oracle 10g, hence, please ignore 11g features.

Comment: so you want a function that takes the output of the last diff and spits it into a table?

Comment: Can you create a sql fiddle for this: sqlfiddle.com

Comment: prefer a query or a function anything which is efficient really

Comment: i tried writing a query, i am no sql expert so need help

Comment: can you post the query you have created?

Comment: So what happens when a revision changes two things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily the prettiest SQL, but this'll do it using pretty generic `CASE` logic.
Since it's an audit table, it assumes no gaps in the revisions to simplify things.

```
SELECT 
 CASE
   WHEN ea1."First_name" <> ea2."First_name" THEN 'First_Name' 
   WHEN ea1."Last_Name"  <> ea2."Last_Name"  THEN 'Last_Name' 
   WHEN ea1."Gender"     <> ea2."Gender"     THEN 'Gender' 
   WHEN ea1."Position"   <> ea2."Position"   THEN 'Position' END "Column_name",
 ea2."Employee_id", ea2."Revision",
 CASE
   WHEN ea1."First_name" <> ea2."First_name" THEN ea1."First_name" 
   WHEN ea1."Last_Name"  <> ea2."Last_Name"  THEN ea1."Last_Name" 
   WHEN ea1."Gender"     <> ea2."Gender"     THEN ea1."Gender" 
   WHEN ea1."Position"   <> ea2."Position"   THEN ea1."Position" END "Old_Value",
 CASE
   WHEN ea1."First_name" <> ea2."First_name" THEN ea2."First_name" 
   WHEN ea1."Last_Name"  <> ea2."Last_Name"  THEN ea2."Last_Name" 
   WHEN ea1."Gender"     <> ea2."Gender"     THEN ea2."Gender" 
   WHEN ea1."Position"   <> ea2."Position"   THEN ea2."Position" END "New_Value"
 FROM EMPLOYEE_AUDIT ea1
 JOIN EMPLOYEE_AUDIT ea2
   ON ea1."Employee_id" = ea2."Employee_id"
  AND ea1."Revision" = ea2."Revision" -1
```

[An SQLFiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1569/1).

EDIT: Since you asked, this is a version using `LAG`, not a big improvement;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT "Employee_id", "Revision", "First_name" fn, "Last_Name" ln,
  "Gender" g, "Position" p, 
  LAG("First_name", 1) OVER 
      (PARTITION BY "Employee_id" ORDER BY "Revision") fn2, 
  LAG("Last_Name", 1)  OVER 
      (PARTITION BY "Employee_id" ORDER BY "Revision") ln2,
  LAG("Gender", 1)  OVER 
      (PARTITION BY "Employee_id" ORDER BY "Revision") g2, 
  LAG("Position",1) OVER 
      (PARTITION BY "Employee_id" ORDER BY "Revision") p2
  FROM EMPLOYEE_AUDIT
)
SELECT 
 CASE
   WHEN fn <> fn2 THEN 'First_Name' WHEN ln <> ln2 THEN 'Last_Name' 
   WHEN g  <> g2  THEN 'Gender' WHEN p  <> p2  THEN 'Position' 
 END "Column_name", "Employee_id", "Revision",
 CASE
   WHEN fn <> fn2 THEN fn2 WHEN ln <> ln2 THEN ln2 
   WHEN g  <> g2  THEN g2  WHEN p  <> p2  THEN p2
 END "Old_Value",
 CASE
   WHEN fn <> fn2 THEN fn  WHEN ln <> ln2 THEN ln 
   WHEN g  <> g2  THEN g   WHEN p  <> p2  THEN p 
 END "New_Value"
FROM cte
WHERE fn2 IS NOT NULL;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/138b4/1).

Comment: i was thinking can we use lag here?

Comment: @user1224036 You could, but I'm not sure it would simplify the statement. You'd still need to do the comparisons in a similar way, only the self join part would disappear.

Comment: example of that too would be very helpful

Comment: @user1224036 Added a lag version.

Comment: These queries don't handle NULL values correctly, but since all fields look they should be mandatory, this is probably ok.

Comment: also this does not work when there is non varchar in one of the table columns

Comment: No the query should handle null values correctly, also varchar, number, date etc

Comment: Sorry, i was only asking help

Comment: @user1224036 If you need more help or need to add requirements that you can't figure out how to add, I suggest you start a new question. More isolated questions are easier to answer, and it makes it easier for people with the same problem to find a solution.